# AutoCAD DWG header to QGIS Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, layout-manager

We would like to implement a header into QGIS layouts. Problem is that the header we received is currently drawn/prepared in .dwg format.

Is there any quick solution to avoid redrawing of received (.dwg) header insider Layout composer in QGIS. Just a form, we are aware that we'll need to add labels manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could export your CAD-header/layout to `svg`, then load the `svg` to the QGIS layout manager and arrange all elements (map, text, legend, etc) so they fit into the layout. I found it easier to recreate the CAD-layout, but decide for yourself.

Comment: Exporting to SVG is a good idea, but you have to print to PDF and convert to SVG afterwards, because AutoCAD has no direct SVG export. You can use Inkscape to convert to SVG.